# Word Counter Code giving me undefined error

Tags: php

I want to write code to count words from a form text area, so far I have `$str=str_word_count($_POST['mytextarea']);`. I have created the textarea and named it but when I tried to access the page it is giving me this error:

> Notice: undefined index: mytextarea in C:\xamp\htdocs\wordcounter.php

Comment: Check if the data is posted.

Comment: Might be a good idea to post your textarea here too.

Comment: I don't really get what you want. Post more code, please.

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST['mytextarea'] requires a form with the POST method used and the field must be named mytextarea.

For example:

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="mytextarea"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

If you load this page without the form being submitted then it will provide the notice as the index "mytextarea" hasn't been added to the global $_POST variable yet.

You can get around this with something similar to:

```
 if (isset($_POST['mytextarea']))
     $str = str_word_count($_POST['mytextarea']);
```